# How to extract only non-empty deques in dict where key-value pair is int - collections.deque pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, vectorization, deque

I have a `dict` of `collection.deque` objects, `dqs`, where the key is some integer `id`. I would like to create another `dict` that only has the entries in `dqs` where the deque is non-empty.

Is there a quick way to do this without iterating through the deque?

Answer (score 1):

Empty deques are falsey, non-empty deques are truthy:

```
>>> bool(deque([]))
False
>>> bool(deque([1, 2]))
True
```

This will not iterate through each deque:

```
non_empty_dqs = {k: v for k, v in dqs.items() if v}
```